# Can you explain the thread profile graph?

Tags: java, regex, multithreading, profiling

I'm new to the java profiling

[image]

I have a thread which reads from a file are do some regex operation on each line. The above picture is the graph that I got from the JVisualVM profiler for my thread.

1. Green is running.
2. Purple is sleeping.
3. Orange is parked

It seems the thread sleep more than running. I know due to File read this is somewhat acceptable. But this seems way more than that.

Can you please explain, does it have anything to do which regex operation or do I need to look for more optimization?

Comment: There are many factors missing from your question which would make it difficult to answer like: What else is running on that machine? How many cores is your box running on? What about memory constraints? How loaded is your box?

Comment: Threads are controlled by an OS scheduler that gives them time to work, to let other threads work, etc. and takes into consideration all the factors mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Harddrives are much more slower than CPUs. I really can't see a problem in profiling output. CPU completes processing and waits for harddrive for reading file(which is a very time consuming operation comparing to arithmetic logic operations).

Comment: I am surprised that this question is still not closed. There is no source code attached to the question, just a vague text description and a colorful scale-less bar. And still the author asks: "please explain ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profiling result is not unexpected for this kind of work.  The thread is sleeping most of the time because of the file access.  To get substantial speed improvements, you will probably have to address file access in some way.